# What is the Ubuntu Accomplishments project?

Tags: community, accomplishments

Recently I heard about a project called Ubuntu Accomplishments.

- What is it?
- What are its advantages?
- And how do I install it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What is it?

The Ubuntu Accomplishments project is designed to provide a means in which you can be awarded trophies for different types of accomplishments in the community and elsewhere. The project is designed for Ubuntu's needs, but actually supports any community and project.

Basically it is a trophy cabinet.

> Features:

- Browse a Library of Opportunities: A wealth of different opportunities are available in the community and on your computer that you can explore.
- Read Step-By-Step Instructions: For each opportunity read step-by-step instructions of how to participate, complete with tips and tricks, pitfalls, and useful reading and support resources.
- Find What You Need...Fast: Opportunities can be filtered by category and sub-categories to find the right kind of opportunities that interest you.
- Discover Accomplishments Automatically
- Deep Desktop: Accomplishments in the community and on your computer are automatic; displaying notification bubbles to indicate when you have accomplished something new.
- Deep Desktop Integration: Ubuntu Accomplishments integrates into your Ubuntu desktop with quicklists, hi-res icons, and a Unity dash lens to access your trophies and opportunities right away.
- Showcase Your Accomplishments: Your trophy collection is easily accessible inside the My Trophies pane, and ready to show to your friends and family.

> Requirements:

- Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin (or higher).
- You need to have a working UbuntuOne Account

> Installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-accomplishments/releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install accomplishments-daemon accomplishments-viewer ubuntu-community-accomplishments
```

> Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

> More information:

- [Official Website](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Accomplishments)
- [jonobacon.org](http://www.jonobacon.org/2012/05/31/help-needed-ask-ubuntu-accomplishment-documentation/)
- [YT example by jonobacon](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uyuy1GiNuwQ)